# String search C program for command prompt

Tags: c, string

I wrote C program of searching string. The problem is `MyStrstr()` function doesn't work with 
command prompt. It only works with IDE. So, can anyone advise me how to fix the code for working with command prompt. With regards...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARGUMENT_COUNT   3              
#define FILE_INDEX       2              
#define SEARCH_INDEX     1              
#define BUFFER           256
#define SUCCESS          0
#define ERRCODE_PARAM    1              
#define ERRCODE_FILENAME 2              
#define MSG_USAGE       "String Search Program === EXER5 === by Newbie\nUsage: %s Search_String fileName"
#define MSG_ERROR       "Can not open file. [%s]"

char* MyStrstr(char* pszSearchString, char* pszSearchWord);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* pFile = NULL;                 
    char szData[BUFFER];
    char* pszCutString = NULL;

    if(argc != ARGUMENT_COUNT) {
        printf(MSG_USAGE, argv[0]);     
        return ERRCODE_PARAM;
    }

    pFile = fopen(argv[FILE_INDEX], "r");
    if(pFile == NULL) {         
        printf(MSG_ERROR, argv[FILE_INDEX]);
        return ERRCODE_FILENAME;
    }

    pszCutString = MyStrstr(szData, argv[SEARCH_INDEX]);
    if(pszCutString != NULL) {
        printf("%s", pszCutString); 
    }

    fclose(pFile);
    pFile = NULL;
    return SUCCESS;
}    

char* MyStrstr(char* pszSearchString, char* pszSearchWord) {

    int nFcount = 0;                    
    int nScount = 0;                    
    int nSearchLen = 0;
    int nIndex = 0;
    char* pszDelString = NULL; 
    char cSLen = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    if(pszSearchString == NULL || pszSearchWord == NULL)   {
        return NULL;
    }   

    while(pszSearchWord[nSearchLen] != '\0') {
        nSearchLen++;
    }                               
    if(nSearchLen <= 0){
        return pszSearchString;
    }

    cSLen = *pszSearchWord++;
    if (!cSLen) {
        return (char*) pszSearchString;
    }

    len = strlen(pszSearchWord);

    do {
        char cMLength;
        do {
            cMLength = *pszSearchString++;
            if (!cMLength)
                return (char *) 0;
        } while (cMLength != cSLen);
    } while (strncmp(pszSearchString, pszSearchWord, len) != 0);
    return (char *) (pszSearchString - 1);  
}
```

Comment: "`doesn't work with command prompt`" in what way does it not work?

Comment: You haven't told us what the input is.  Presumably you passed it some command line params, and one of those looks to be a file.  We need to know the ***Input*** if we are going to debug it.

Comment: What is the `fopen()` doing there? The file is never used, it's just closed again. This is a strange and hard to understand program.

Comment: You never use your file pointer for anything. You're searching an indeterminate buffer `szData` for something provided by cmdline args. This didn't work in the IDE either (not *this* code, anyway).

Comment: There are three parameters. 1st is ".exe file name", 2nd is "String I want to search" and 3rd is "text file name". Sorry about that. I forget it.

Comment: This is my complete program. Find the String that is entered form parameter in the text file and then output the user.

Comment: Ignoring the code for the moment, are you running the program from the command prompt, or just opening the file from Explorer? Because unless you pause some way or another it will close immediately after returning. Visual Studio adds a pause by default, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to open a file, search the contents of that file for a string and return/print that. You are instead doing:

```
char szData[256];          // <-- making an uninitialized buffer
char* pszCutString = NULL;

pFile = fopen(argv[2], "r");              // <-- Opening a file
pszCutString = MyStrstr(szData, argv[1]); // <-- searching the buffer
if(pszCutString != NULL) {
    printf("%s", pszCutString); 
}
fclose(pFile);        // <-- Closing the file
```

So you **never** fill your buffer `szData` with the contents of the file noted in `argv[2]`. You're trying to search an uninitialized buffer for a string. You're luck the result is just "no output comes out".

You need to take the contents of the file in `argv[2]` and place it in the buffer `szData` then do the search. This could be accomplished by adding a call to a function like [read()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) or [fscanf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf)

Note 1:
I assume when you say this "worked" in the IDE, the code was a little different and you weren't using the command line arguments.

Note 2:
you should also check to `fopen()` worked before trying to read from/close `pFile`, and if your file is possibly larger than 256 characters you will need to change your code to either have a dynamically sized string, or you'll need to loop the buffer fills (but then you have to worry about breaking a word apart), or some other mechanism to check the full file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Mike. I also initialized the Buffer size and the content in the text file in argv[2] is  "aabccdeegfhccad". But nothing comes out. I also think there is a difference in MyStrstr() function but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Newbie - I'm not talking about the text in the file. You open a file, then close the file. You do not **read** anything from the file. You have to `read()` or `fscanf()` something from `pFile` to `szData` before you call `MyStrstr()` or this will never work.

Comment: Arr...I got it. Thank you so much for your explaining and your answer.